# getting links array of arrays JSON

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

The bottom line is that I have a working code. All perfectly. I receive data without any problem, but I can not figure out how to get the data from the array of arrays.
Here JSON code.
Help me, please)

```
{  
   "timestamp":1470642450,
   "type":"news",
   "rows":[  
      {  
         "categorytitle":"Происшествия",
         "dateline":"1470641760",
         "media":[  
            {  
               "width":"200",
               "filename":"https://www.****.ru/media/8c/8c/bomba(2)__79cnk5i.jpg",
               "height":"133"
            }
         ],
         "text":"<div>\r\n<div>\r\n<div>\r\n<div>\r\n<div>\r\n<div>\r\n<div>\r\n<div>\r\n<div>\r\n<div>\r\n<div>\r\n<div>\r\n<div dir="         auto">
На Дону 6 августа был обнаружен склад боеприпасов Великой Отечественной войны.  
Находка была обнаружена около 17:20         в заброшенном саду хутора Демидовка,
         Алексеевского сельского поселения (Матвеево-Курганский район ) 
.<br /><br /><em> 
"При проведении земляных работ при корчевке деревьев были найдены 123 снаряда времен Великой Отечественной войны 80 и 75 калибра"
</em>,
         <em> <span>&ndash; </span></em>сообщает пресс-служба ДПЧС по Ростовской области.<br /><br />Сейчас место обнаружения находится под охраной сотрудников полиции. Подана заявка на разминирование.</div>\r\n</div>\r\n</div>\r\n</div>\r\n</div>\r\n</div>\r\n</div> 
\r\n</div>\r\n</div>\r\n</div>\r\n</div>\r\n</div>\r\n</div>\r\n<div>\r\n<div>\r\n<div> 
\r\n<div><a><img src="filesystem:         https://*****.org/temporary/702229962_26779_5859320227133863146.jpg" />
</a><a><span data-content="t1"></span></a><a><em></em></a></div>\r\n</div>\r\n</div>\r\n</div>",
         "link":"https://www.*****.ru/news/401647/",
         "username":"Татьяна Карпухина",
         "categoryid":"7",
         "title":"На Дону в заброшенном саду нашли склад боеприпасов времен ВОВ",
         "anouns":"В Ростовской области при проведении земляных работ в заброшенном саду были найдены 123 снаряда Великой Отечественной войны",
         "newsid":"401647"
      },
      {  
         "categorytitle":"Происшествия",
         "dateline":"1470641040",
         "media":[  
            {  
               "width":"200",
               "filename":"https://www.****.ru/media/b9/b9/antiterror_b05__0.jpg",
               "height":"133"
            }
         ],
         "text":"<p lang="         ru-RU">В Дагестане в селе Айваки Гергебильского района нашли два предмета,
         похожие на взрывные устройства. 
</p>\r\n<p lang="ru-RU">Полицейские обнаружили подозрительные предметы в частном доме,
         сообщает  
<a href="http://tass.ru/proisshestviya/3518193" target="_blank">ТАСС</a>.</p>\r\n<p lang="ru-RU">На месте работают взрывотехники МВД и ФСБ.</p>",
         "link":"https://www.****.ru/news/401646/",
         "username":"Маша Волобуева",
         "categoryid":"7",
         "title":"В Дагестане в частном доме нашли похожие на взрывчатку предметы",
         "anouns":"На месте работают взрывотехники МВД и ФСБ",
         "newsid":"401646"
      },

   ]
```

And some Activity code. (I want get URL in rows-media-filename.)

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void...params) {
     // Create an array
     arraylist = new ArrayList < HashMap < String, String >> ();
     // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
     jsonobject = JSONfunctions
         .getJSONfromURL("http://www.****.ru/cgi-bin/kernel.cgi?module=news&act=get_json&type=news&json_response=1&media=1");


     try {
         // Locate the array name in JSON
         jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("rows");
         for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
             HashMap < String, String > map = new HashMap < String, String > ();
             jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

             map.put("title", jsonobject.getString("title"));
             map.put("text", jsonobject.getString("text"));
             // Set the JSON Objects into the array
             arraylist.add(map);
         }
     } catch (JSONException e) {
         Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
     return null;
 }
```

Comment: Check this link if it provides you any help, [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38574925/retrieving-nested-arrays-values-with-json-java/38575643#38575643](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38574925/retrieving-nested-arrays-values-with-json-java/38575643#38575643)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the values of media which is present inside rows using the below code.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
    JSONArray result = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("rows");
    for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObject1 = (JSONObject) result.get(i);
        JSONArray jsonarray1 = (JSONArray) jsonObject1.get("media");
        for (int j = 0; j < jsonarray1.size(); j++) {
            System.out.println(((JSONObject) jsonarray1.get(j)).get(
                    "height").toString());
            System.out.println(((JSONObject) jsonarray1.get(j)).get(
            "width").toString());
            System.out.println(((JSONObject) jsonarray1.get(j)).get(
            "filename").toString());
        }

    }
```

Comment: I have a ImageLoader class and I need to URL to static string

Comment: instead of printing you can assign it to the string.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a valid JSON data. Please check your josn before parsing. If JSON is valid then parse by key-value pair. For check JSON by through 
[JSON Validity](http://jsonlint.com/)