# JSONException: Issues trying to retrieve data from JSON

Tags: java, android, json

Alright so I'm attempting to pull data from JSON's lists such as this:

```
{"code":200,"status":"OK","data":{"timings":{"Fajr":"04:17","Sunrise":"05:30","Dhuhr":"12:20","Asr":"15:42","Sunset":"19:11","Maghrib":"19:11","Isha":"20:24","Imsak":"04:07","Midnight":"00:20"},"date":{"readable":"17 Jun 2017","timestamp":"1497652236"}}}
```

exclusively the specific prayers. My code to find the data is as follows:

```
 class SaveTheFeed extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    String jsonString = "";
    String result = "";
    EditText chosenCity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    String city = chosenCity.getText().toString();

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://api.aladhan.com/timingsByCity?city=" + city + "&country=AE&method=2");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        InputStream inputStream;

        try{
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            inputStream = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) !=null){
                builder.append(line + "\n");
            }
            jsonString = builder.toString();

            JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);

            JSONObject data = (JSONObject) jObject.get("data");

            JSONArray jArray = (JSONArray) data.get("timings");

            outputTimings(jArray);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        TextView prayerTimes = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.prayerTimes);
        prayerTimes.setText(result);
    }

    protected void outputTimings(JSONArray jsonArray){
        String[] prayers= {"Fajr", "Sunrise", "Dhuhr", "Asr", "Sunset", "Maghrib", "Isha", "Imsak", "Midnight"};
        try{
            for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                JSONObject cityObject =
                        jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                result = result +  prayers[i] + " : "+
                         cityObject.getString(prayers[i]) + "\n";
            }
```

I get this error that points towards line 85 (the  JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(jsonString); line)

> 06-17 00:24:15.973 2866-2907/azanmute.android.com.azanmute W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value  of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
>   06-17 00:24:15.973 2866-2907/azanmute.android.com.azanmute W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
>   06-17 00:24:15.974 2866-2907/azanmute.android.com.azanmute W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:160)
>   06-17 00:24:15.974 2866-2907/azanmute.android.com.azanmute W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:173)
>   06-17 00:24:15.974 2866-2907/azanmute.android.com.azanmute W/System.err:     at azanmute.android.com.azanmute.MainActivity$SaveTheFeed.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:85)
>   06-17 00:24:15.974 2866-2907/azanmute.android.com.azanmute W/System.err:     at azanmute.android.com.azanmute.MainActivity$SaveTheFeed.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:60)
>   06-17 00:24:15.974 2866-2907/azanmute.android.com.azanmute W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305)
>   06-17 00:24:15.974 2866-2907/azanmute.android.com.azanmute W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>   06-17 00:24:15.974 2866-2907/azanmute.android.com.azanmute W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
>   06-17 00:24:15.974 2866-2907/azanmute.android.com.azanmute W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
>   06-17 00:24:15.974 2866-2907/azanmute.android.com.azanmute W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
>   06-17 00:24:15.974 2866-2907/azanmute.android.com.azanmute W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)

So my understanding is that Im pointing towards the data incorrectly or mixed up JSONObjects with JSONArrays. Ive already tried both [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10267910/jsonexception-value-of-type-java-lang-string-cannot-be-converted-to-jsonobject) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38574925/retrieving-nested-arrays-values-with-json-java) but still receive the same error.

Comment: From the exception, I'd say the problem is your String jsonString is not a valid JSON string. Can you put a debug here and provide the exact value of jsonString just before l. 85?

Comment: Just print what you are getting in HTTP response to be sure the URL sends you a valid json response

Comment: So which is line 85 of `MainActivity.java`? It's *always* useful to reduce things to a [mcve] - there's a lot of irrelevant code in your question at the moment.

Comment: Aside from anything else, `timings` *isn't* an array - it's another object...

Comment: Your json string on the top is correct, but the error log is say that it's not correct. Then let's use the debugger to print out the jsonString before the `new JSONObject(jsonString);` to check it out

Comment: Bear with me please :D I'm still new at this. I added Log.d(TAG, jsonString); and it gave me this:
 **Method not allowed. Must be one of: GET**

Comment: once try it -> JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(jsonString.toString());

Comment: timings is not an array so parse it in an object

Answer (score 1):

You haven't confused JSON Object and JSON Array in this case. This is definitely a JSONObject.

It's possible that you've added 'invisible' characters to your string that the JSONObject constructor doesn't like (i.e. "\n"). Try this:

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(jsonString.substring(jsonString.indexOf("{"), jsonString.lastIndexOf("}") + 1));
```

Also please note that "timings" is also a JSONObject and not a JSONArray. Example of a JSONArray, where "cars" is the JSONArray:

```
{"name":"John","age":30,"cars":[ "Ford", "BMW", "Fiat" ]}
```

Comment: I went ahead and I try adding your line. It still errors but this time its different error:
`org.json.JSONException: Unterminated object at character 84 of {
           padding:30px;
         font:12px/1.5 Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
         }
         h1{
         margin:0;
             font-weight:normal;
               line-height:48px;
    }`
with the issue remaining in the same line

Comment: @Fencer300 could you post the error for our information?
Edit: thanks

Comment: @Fencer300 your HTTP request isn't returning a valid JSON, it's returning the HTML page content.

Comment: Haha screw me. [This](http://api.aladhan.com/timingsByCity?city=Dubai&country=AE&method=2) is exactly what I have it requesting. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: See the documentation for JSONObject here:
https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject-java.lang.String-

The issue is almost certainly with your JSON. Try printing/logging whatever comes back into your jsonString and pasting it into a tool like https://jsonlint.com/ to check it is valid.

Comment: @DanCarter I did and it prints out just fine. I double checked the source of the api page and it has zero html in it so im confused why im getting an html error